# PythonとSwiftでZlibの圧縮結果が違うものになる

Tags: python, swift

Python3.7で以下のコードを試したところ、出力結果は789c4b4c4c4c040003ce0185でした。

```
import zlib

message = "aaaa"

#文字列をbytes型に変換
testData = message.encode("utf-8")
#zlibで圧縮
compressedData = zlib.compress(testData)
#16進数文字列に変換
hexString = compressedData.hex()
print(hexString)
```

Swift5で以下のコードを試したところ、出力結果は4B4C4C4C0400でした。

```
import Foundation

let testString = "aaaa"
//文字列をdata型(byte型)に変換
if let testData = testString.data(using: .utf8)
{
    //zlibで圧縮
    let compressedData = try (testData as NSData).compressed(using: .zlib)
    
    // 各バイトを16進数の文字列に変換。
    let stringArray = compressedData.map{String(format: "%02X", $0)}
    // 16進数を結合する。
    let hexString = stringArray.joined()
    
    print(hexString)
}
```

Python側ではヘッダーとチェックサムがついているのに対してSwift側ではヘッダーとチェックサムが抜けているようです。

Swiftで生成した、ヘッダーとチェックサムが抜けているデータをPython側で受け取る(decompressとdecodeで逆変換する)には、どうしたら良いでしょうか？　または、Swift側でヘッダーとチェックサムを付与させる方法があったりするのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下は Python側での処理です

- 2バイトのヘッダーと4バイトのチェックサムを取り除く

```py
zlib.compress(mesg.encode())[2:-4]
```

- ヘッダーとチェックサム無しのデータを取り扱う

```py
zlib.decompress(data, -15).decode()
```

参考: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089662/python-inflate-and-deflate-implementations

Comment: 質問とは関係ないけれど, PlantUML 扱う時に, この処理が利用できます

Answer (score 3):

Python側で対応する方法が回答としてついているので、こちらは不要かもしれませんが一応Swift側でも対応できそうと言うことで。

参考記事はこちら。
[Compress and decompress zlib (RFC 1950) using DEFLATE (RFC 1951) functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59000830/6541007)

```
import Foundation
import zlib

let testString = "aaaa"
//文字列をdata型(byte型)に変換
if let testData = testString.data(using: .utf8)
{
    //zlibで圧縮
    let compressedData = try (testData as NSData).compressed(using: .zlib)
    
    //チェックサム(Adler-32)を計算
    let adler = testData.withUnsafeBytes {bufPtr in
        adler32(
            1,
            bufPtr.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: Bytef.self),
            uInt(bufPtr.count))
    }
    //print(String(format: "%08X", adler))

    //ヘッダとチェックサムを付加したデータを作成
    let zlibData = Data([0x78, 0x9C]) + (compressedData as Data)
        + Data([UInt8(adler >> 24),
                UInt8((adler >> 16) & 0xFF),
                UInt8((adler >> 8) & 0xFF),
                UInt8(adler & 0xFF)])
    // 各バイトを16進数の文字列に変換。
    let stringArray = zlibData.map {String(format: "%02X", $0)}
    // 16進数を結合する。
    let hexString = stringArray.joined()
    
    print(hexString)
}
```