# PythonとSwiftでLZ4の圧縮結果が違うものになる

Tags: python, swift

PythonとSwiftでLZ4圧縮を使用した後に16進数文字列に変更すると、それぞれ異なる結果になりました。

Python3.7で以下のコードを試したところ、出力結果は`04224d1868400400000000000000cd040000806162636400000000`でした。

```
import lz4.frame
testString = "abcd"
compressedData = lz4.frame.compress(testString.encode("utf-8"))
hexString = compressedData.hex()
print(hexString)
```

Swift5で以下のコードを実行すると、出力結果は`6276342D040000006162636462763424`でした。

```
import Foundation

let testString = "abcd"

//Convert string to data type (byte)
if let testData = testString.data(using: .utf8)
{
    //Compressed by lz4
    let compressedData = try (testData as NSData).compressed(using: .lz4)

    // Convert each byte to a string of hexadecimal digits.
    let stringArray = compressedData.map{String(format: "%02X", $0)}

    // Combine hexadecimal numbers.
    let hexString = stringArray.joined()
    print(hexString)
}
```

Swiftで圧縮したデータをPythonで解答したいと考えているため、SwiftでのLZ4圧縮データをPythonに合わせたいです。以前、[Zlibの場合について回答頂いた](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/80755/python%E3%81%A8swift%E3%81%A7zlib%E3%81%AE%E5%9C%A7%E7%B8%AE%E7%B5%90%E6%9E%9C%E3%81%8C%E9%81%95%E3%81%86%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B)のですが、LZ4でもそういったことは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 参考: [COMPRESSION_LZ4 | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compression/compression_algorithm/compression_lz4)

Comment: ここ参考になるかも？ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47603583/swift-compression-doesnt-decompress-lz4-image
(ちなみに 質問の Pythonコードからファイルに出力したものを, Rustで展開はできました)